# How to group associations error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model which `has_one :address, as: :addressable`. Here address is a polymorphic association.

When saving the user, if it errors out. Because of failing validations, Errors are not grouped for address

The output of `user.errors.to_json` is

```
"{\"address.city\":[\"can't be blank\"],\"address.state\":[\"can't be blank\"],\"address.country\":[\"can't be blank\"],\"address.zipcode\":[\"can't be blank\",\"is invalid\"],\"address.business_phone\":[\"is invalid\"],\"name\":[\"can't be blank\"]}"
```

I would like the output to be

```
"address: {city: ["can't be blank], state: ["can't be blank]..}"
```

Is it possible to group the error messages or exclude the error messages of the association?

Because `user.address.errors` seem to give what I need, but I need to get the user model errors without the errors of address model.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `JSON.parse(user.errors)`

Answer (score 1):

A working solution

```
# Note: This modifies the given Hash
def extract_address_errors_from_user_errors!(user_errors_hash)
  address_error_prefix = 'address.'
  empty_str = ''

  address_error_keys = []

  address = Address.new

  user_errors_hash.each do |k, v|
    unless k.start_with?(address_error_prefix)
      next
    end

    # Collect the address error keys to later remove them from user errors hash
    address_error_keys << k

    address_attr_name = k.gsub(address_error_prefix, empty_str)

    address_attr_name_sym = address_attr_name.to_sym

    address.errors.add(address_attr_name_sym, v)

    address.errors[address_attr_name_sym].flatten!
  end
  
  # Remove the address errors from user errors
  user_errors_hash.except!(*address_error_keys)

  address.errors.to_hash
end
```

**Usage**

```
user_errors_hash = user.errors.to_hash
address_errors_hash = extract_address_errors_from_user_errors!(user_errors_hash)

user_errors_hash.merge!(address: address_errors_hash)

# This should give you the desired output
user_errors_hash.to_json
```